# Xamarin Android app crashes on android just after launch. Missing MonoRuntimeProvider

Tags: android, xamarin, mono

I uninstalled Xamarin on Mac. Then re-installed it. 6.1.4 (Build1).
Now I created a new Solution. With Portable Class Library selected. Then I compiled. Then I installed on simulator running on same machine. But at the launch itself the App failed. Then I checked Application Output. Below is the log. I am not able to proceed. Please help. I checked: "Xamarin.Android API-23 Support" and "Mono runtime" are installed on the simulator android. (Uninstalling these components also did not solve)

Thanks in advance.

Below is the log:

```
am start -n "in.test.buttonlogger/md50a143af76fade5fdcdfca266ac349d28.MainActivity"
Starting: Intent { cmp=in.test.buttonlogger/md50a143af76fade5fdcdfca266ac349d28.MainActivity }

[art] Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
[art] Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
[AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[AndroidRuntime] Process: in.kosi.buttonlogger, PID: 6621
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5856)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:38)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 10 more
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Xamarin.Android.Platform
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:345)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:327)
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:32)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Check this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10159/can-no-longer-run-android-applications-using-xamarin-4-2-and-xamarin-android-4-10-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you experience this issue, the normal solution is to simply edit the `AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk` property in your `.csproj` file for the given project to `false` as follows:

```
<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>False</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
```

If that doesn't work, then try disabling `Shared Runtime` in the `Project Properties` under `Android Options`.

As a last option, you can also try to decrease your `Target Framework` in the `Project Properties` under `General`.

Comment: Yes. Setting AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk to false in the file .//Droid/ttteest.Droid.csproj solved it. But any GUI way of doing it while creating the project itself?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But you can always provide feedback to Xamarin if you've got a specific request.

Comment: Is this a normal bug? my first android app and i had to disabled shared runtime. Just used the visual studio 2019 templates to create xamarin app for android and ios.